# Can the Scala parser framework parse a sequence supplied in "push" mode?

Tags: parsing, scala

Can I use the Scala parser framework to parse a stream of events supplied to the parser in push mode (i.e. a sequence of write() calls)? Or does it have to "pull" its input using iterators? I'm looking at using the parser primarily to validate that the sequence of write() calls is a well-formed legitimate sequence, but it might also inject additional tokens into the stream.

I know I can push a sequence of tokens to a component that expects to pull the sequence by using threads, but that's a messy solution.

Comment: You push it into a FIFO buffer and let the parser read from that (blocking, if applicable)? There are some technical details to be handled, but will this do what you want? What would be different from what you want? Reading again, is this the solution you are talking about in the last paragraph? I don't think you can do without threads, since the state of the parser has to be stored somewhere (and the parser framework uses the call stack for that).

Comment: I guess it depends whether the parser that's generated is top-down or bottom up. If it's top-down, then it relies on the program stack extensively for maintaining state. If it's bottom-up, then it only needs to maintain the current position in a finite state automaton; but then that assumes that the grammar will be unambiguous with no need for backtracking so a single state number is all that's needed.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation come to mind, there is a implementation for Scala. How to make it work with the parser framework is another story.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think coroutines or continuations will do the job unless the parser is designed and written that way. Can anyone tell me what kind of parser gets generated? If it generates an FSA then there's probably a low-level API that allows one to drive the transitions in the FSA in push mode.

Comment: @MichaelKay The generated parsers are recursive-decsent parsers.

Comment: Thanks. Well if it's recursive descent then it needs to own the program stack, so it's either got to be in a separate thread, or I can forget it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, the answer appears to be that the Scala parser needs to "own the control loop": it can't be driven in push mode. This is because as a recursive descent parsing engine, it needs the program stack to maintain state. It could potentially operate on a separate stack by running it as an independent thread, but of course one would have to think about whether the grammar requires backtracking and/or lookahead and implement any necessary buffering.

For the purpose intended, finding a tool that generates a simple state machine seems a better way forward.

Thanks for the comments that led to this conclusion.